# How to combine 2 dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, rbind

I have 2 dataframes as below. Dataframe 1 has timestamp from june 2017 to Sept 2017. And Dataframe 2 has timestamp from Jan 15th to Jan 18th 2018.

**I need to combine both of these dataframes**, without losing any data.

The column names are same in both the dataset.

**Dataframe 1 : 382 observation; 38 variables; Timestamp : 1-15-2018 to 1-18-2018**

**Dataframe 2 : 9567 observation ; 34 variables ; Timestamp : 6-6-2017 to 9-13-2017**

*Dataframe 1 :*

```
  TimeStamp         A        B         C    D        E        F     G   H
  1/15/2018 0:00    49.9238  62.2187   0    52.3125  63.457   49    84  54
  1/15/2018 0:15    49.8437  62.4817   0    52.3125  58.593   49    84  54
  1/15/2018 0:30    50.2187  62.3932   0    52.625   75.995   49    84  54
```

*Dataframe 2 :*

```
TimeStamp       D   A       B       E       C       F
6/6/2017 0:00   54  71.94   71.94   44.684  79.06   40.996
6/6/2017 0:15   53  71.94   71.63   45.966  80.06   40.708
6/6/2017 0:30   54  73.44   72.06   46.088  77.81   40.845
6/6/2017 0:45   54  73.88   72.06   46.704  83.56   40.654
6/6/2017 1:00   52  72.81   71.75   47.144  78.19   40.685
```

Comment: check out `plyr::rbind.fill`? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.4/topics/rbind.fill

Comment: Thanks, but in my case the number of columns are around 38, hence i wont be able to manually include them in the code, as its suggested in the link provided above.

Comment: e.g. usage: `plyr::rbind.fill(df1, df2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data frames are called `df1`and `df2`, this is an easy solution using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
df.new <- bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

By default, this procedure will keep all columns that appear in any of the data frames.

Comment: Good explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You have another possible solution. Suppose you got dataframes `df1` and `df2`.

```
library(dplyr)
df.merged <- union_all(df1, df2)
```

**Note:** The `union_all` differs from `bind_rows` in one sense that if both dataframes have same columns then `union_all` removes duplicate column whereas `bind_rows` keeps duplicate rows. If both dataframes got different number of columns (may be few common column names) then all columns will be included in merged dataframe.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use **cbind** to join two data frame

```
df.new <- cbind(df1, df2)
```